# How can I efficiently search for the most recent rows where a column matches any result from a different query?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT      NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE friends (
    user_id        BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    friend_user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    UNIQUE (user_id, friend_user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id      BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT    NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    content TEXT      NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX posts_user_id_id_index ON posts(user_id, id);
```

Each user can unilaterally follow any number of friends. The `posts` table has a large number of rows and is rapidly growing.

My goal is to retrieve the 10 most recent posts of a user's friends. This query gives the correct result, but is inefficient:

```
SELECT posts.id, users.name, posts.content
FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE posts.user_id IN (SELECT friend_user_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1)
ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

If the user's friends have recently posted, the query is still reasonably fast ([query plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/6ykR)). But if the user's friends haven't recently posted or the user has no friends, it quickly deteriorates ([query plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/OnoG)).

If I match only a single post author (e.g. `WHERE posts.user_id = 5`), Postgres uses the index `posts_user_id_id_index`. But if I use `IN`, the index doesn't appear to be used at all.

How can I get these results more efficiently?

I've uploaded the schema and the queries I've tried to [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cf1489b7f6d53c3fe0b55ed7ccbad1f0). The output of `SELECT version()` is `PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit` for me.

Comment: I think that your model was missing date field, because the mostly recently activity can be an edition in one post. Try to add a create and update date add an index an try to filter and order in those fileds.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your comment, but the `id` column in `posts` is guaranteed to be strictly increasing. As a primary key it is also indexed. Ordering by it already returns the most recent rows, regardless of the missing date field.